# How do i pass from a class component to a separate api component the search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```
**its a recipe app and i'm stuck on passing search input to the api.
 this are two separate components**
```

this is the component that does the search:

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

   handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Search;
```

**im trying that value in the state Search component will pass to the api:**
    currently im getting state is undefined and the same when use props

```
const key = "***";
const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${this.state.search}&page=2`;

export const recipesData = () =>{
    const recipesData = fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    return recipesData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add method to your class or pass state to receiptsData function;

```
export const recipesData = (search) =>{
    const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${search}&page=2`;

    const recipesData = fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    return recipesData;
```

or

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

   handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${this.state.search}&page=2`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
})
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Search;
```

Comment: thanks that helped :) but now im stuck on how to pass the result from search.js to app.js state

Comment: Create a method in app.js. Then pass this method as a prop to search comoponent. And in search, instead of doing fetch there, just call app method received from props

Comment: still wrecking my brain over it ): this is what i did in **app.js**: `class App extends Component {
  state = {
    recipes: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    recipesData()
      .then(data => this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes }))
  }

  onDataChange = (recipesInfo) => {
      this.setState({
        recipes: recipesInfo        
      })
    }`  this is inside the "app div": `<div className="App">
        <Search callbackFromParent={this.onDataChange} />
        <RecipeList data={this.state.recipes} />
      </div>`   in the Search component i`m completely lost...

Comment: exactly. And in Search component you will receive `callbackFromParent` prop, which you should call when you send the search form in submit. In `handleSubmit` you will call `this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.search)`
P.D. I should call callbackFromParent -> onDataChange. But for the porpouse, will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using React Hook:

```js
const Search = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const fetchRecipesData = url => {
    return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  };
  
  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    const key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${value}&page=2`;
    
    console.log(fetchRecipesData(url));
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button type='submit'>Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Search />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```